# How execute Python code and pass argument via Batch file -using argparse

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, cmd, arguments, argparse

I'm trying to execute Python code via the Batch file without having to hard code the arguments into the python lines. Instead, I would like to specify any additional arguments on the batch itself.
But when I'm running the .bat file nothing Is happening.

My process:

Created a function in the Python code with -argparse that looking for arguments and credentials.

Created a Batch file that 'should' gives the arguments and credentials.

Function in the Python code: **image2json.py**

```
import os
import imghdr
import json


version = "1.0.0.1"

downscale = 2048

bytelimit = 9000000
countlimit = 16

inputdir = None
outputdir = None
authjson = None


def get_args() -> dict:
    import argparse
    # Parse external arguments, and return as dictionary
    arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    arg_parser.add_argument(
        "-i", "--inputpath",
        required=True,
        help="The path to the input folder.")
    arg_parser.add_argument(
        "-o",
        "--outputpath",
        required=True,
        help="The path to the output folder.")
    arg_parser.add_argument(
        "-c",
        "--credentials",
        required=True,
        help="The path to the credentials JSON-file.")

    return vars(arg_parser.parse_args())
args = get_args()

inputdir = args['inputpath']
outputdir = args['outputpath']
authjson = args['credentials']


def load_image(file_path: str, flags=None):
    import imageio
    import cv2

    ext = file_path[-3:].lower()
    if ext != "gif":
        return cv2.imread(file_path, flags)
    else:
        gif = imageio.mimread(file_path)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(gif[0], cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        return img


def build_error_json(message: str):
    import json
    error_dict = dict()
    error_dict['error'] = message
    serialized = json.dumps(error_dict)
    return serialized

def batch_request(image_batch):
    from google.cloud import vision_v1
    from google.cloud.vision_v1 import enums
    from google.cloud.vision_v1 import types
    from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson
    

    annotator_client = vision_v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.from_service_account_json(authjson)

    features = [
        types.Feature(type=enums.Feature.Type.TEXT_DETECTION)  #TEXT_DETECTION DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION
    ]

    requests = []

    for name, image in image_batch.items():
        request = types.AnnotateImageRequest(image = image, features = features)
        requests.append(request)

    response = annotator_client.batch_annotate_images(requests)

    for name, annotation_response in zip(image_batch.keys(), response.responses):

        out_json = os.path.join(outputdir, name + ".json")

        if annotation_response.error.message:
            print("Annotation Error: " + name)
            serialized = build_error_json(response.error.message)
            with open(out_json, "w") as o:
                o.write(serialized)
            continue
            
        try:
            if (len(annotation_response.full_text_annotation.text) > 0):
                serialized = MessageToJson(annotation_response.full_text_annotation)
            else:
                serialized = build_error_json("Text not found.")
        except Exception as e:
            serialized = build_error_json(str(e))

        print("Annotation Done: " + name)

        with open(out_json, "w") as o:
            o.write(serialized)      


def get_credentials():
    try:
        auth = os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']
    except:
        auth = None

    if (authjson is not None):
        print('The credentials taken from system environment')
        return auth

    dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

    jsons = list()

    (_, _, filenames) = next(os.walk(dirname))
    for file in filenames:
        if file.endswith(".json"):
             jsons.append(os.path.join(dirname, file))

    if (len(jsons) == 1):
        print('The credentials taken from local json: ' + os.path.basename(jsons[0]))
        return jsons[0]
    else:
        print('Credentials is not found. Please specify the credentials explicitly.')
        return None


def detect_text_batch(imagefiles):
    import io
    import numpy as np
    import tempfile
    import cv2
    from google.cloud.vision_v1 import types
    

    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdirname:
        current_batch_size = 0
        current_batch_images = dict()
        for path in imagefiles:
            image_name = os.path.basename(path)
            try:
                m = load_image(path, cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
            except Exception as e:
                print("File opening error: " + image_name)
                out_json = os.path.join(outputdir, image_name + ".json")
                serialized = build_error_json(str(e))
                continue
            h, w = m.shape[:2]
            maxside = max(w, h)
            scale = downscale / maxside
            if (scale < 1):
                m = cv2.resize(m, dsize=(0, 0), fx=scale, fy=scale)
            tmp_path = os.path.join(tmpdirname, image_name) + '.jpg'
            cv2.imwrite(tmp_path, m, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 90])
            if (os.path.exists(tmp_path)):
                with io.open(tmp_path, 'rb') as image_file:
                    content = image_file.read()
                    size = len(content)
                    if (current_batch_size + size >= bytelimit or len(current_batch_images) == countlimit):
                        batch_request(current_batch_images)
                        current_batch_images.clear()
                        current_batch_size = 0
                    
                    image = types.Image(content = content)
                    current_batch_size = current_batch_size + size
                    current_batch_images[image_name] = image
            else:
                #report error
                print("Tempfile saving error: " + image_name)
                out_json = os.path.join(outputdir, image_name + ".json")
                serialized = build_error_json('Tempfile saving error! ' + image_name)
                with open(out_json, "w") as o:
                    o.write(serialized)

        if (len(current_batch_images) > 0):
            batch_request(current_batch_images)

print('Version: ' + version)

args = get_args()

inputdir = args['inputpath']
outputdir = args['outputpath']
authjson = args['credentials']

if (authjson is None):
    print('Credentials is not specified, starting auto search...')
    authjson = get_credentials()

(_, _, filenames) = next(os.walk(inputdir))

imagefiles = list()

for filename in filenames:
    fullpath = os.path.join(inputdir, filename)
    if (imghdr.what(fullpath) is not None):
        imagefiles.append(fullpath)
    else:
        print("Not an image: " + filename)
        out_json = os.path.join(outputdir, filename + ".json")
        serialized = build_error_json("Not an image.")
        with open(out_json, "w") as o:
            o.write(serialized)

if (len(imagefiles) > 0):
    detect_text_batch(imagefiles)
```

---

What the Batch file contains: **myStart.bat**

```
python "image2json.py" -i "C:\Project\images" -o "C:\Project\json" -c "C:\Project\\VisionCredentials.json"
```

Batch file showing that running with no errors, but the image2json.py file didn't executed.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python "C:\Project\image2json.py" -i ./images -o ./json -c VisionCredentials.json
Version: 1.0.0.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Project\image2json.py", line 202, in <module>
    (_, _, filenames) = next(os.walk(inputdir))
StopIteration
```

---

Screenshot of directory:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB6mL.png)

I would like to ask if anyone can help me understand how  I can fix it in the best proper way.

The goal is to execute the 'image2json.py' file when running the 'Start.bat' file.
The concept of code is OCR results. Detailed: extract the text of an image file as JSON file using google vision API.

> It's my first time asking a question so, please feel free to ask me to
> add/edit anything that is missing or make you feel that could be
> helped you understand the topic.
> Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is the current issue you are experiencing with this? You need to tell us what does/doesn't happen, error codes etc. And what is the purpose of `%` in `%-i`?

Comment: Ok, so one thing you need to do is to rename your batch file to something else. `start` is an internal command to `cmd`. So rename to `myStart.cmd` Then use the following line in the `batch-file` and see what happens. `python "%~dp0image2json.py" -i ./images -o ./json -c VisionCredentials.json`

Comment: can you post your errors in the question, by editing it?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is permission errors, it sees the files, but specifically says there is an error opening it. Does the credentials JSON file have the correct credentials? have you manually tested any of these files?

Comment: Yes, the vision API is functional. The credentials are correct, I just test it to be sure.
https://prnt.sc/119nzpo

Comment: ok, I am trying to see why the exception is raised, i cannot test this as I would need to duplicate your environment. I can see where the error comes from, I need to find out why.

Comment: I just found that google has changed the library syntax name. changed ```vision``` to ```vision_v1```

Comment: ok, did you change it in your script?

Comment: Yes, nothing changed.

Comment: @Gerhard you were right. I run it as admin and pass it, but with another error.

Comment: That is different, because administrator starts in `C:\windows\system32` it expects the images folder there. rather use full path `python "%~dp0image2json.py" -i "C:\Project\images" -o "C:\Project\json" -c "C:\Project\\VisionCredentials.json"`

Comment: The problem was with the environment directory library path. I fix it so it can gain access and it running correctly. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Cool, glad you are sorted.

Answer (score 0):

```
set ARG1="-i ./images"
set ARG2="-o ./json"
set ARG3="-c VisionCredentials.json"
python C:\Project\image2json.py %ARG1% %ARG2% %ARG3%
```

try this.

Comment: Thanks but, the point is to control the arguments from the batch file. So even if the directories or the location of the .py files change, you should gonna be able to handle it just by editing the batch file.